# get error messages for all fields on yup revalidation

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-hook-form, yup

i'm trying to validate in react and yup this scenario:

We have two select fields, each one have number that represents hours.

The initial hour should be minor than the final

When we choose an invalid hour, the field is validated and shows the error

if we solve the situation changing the another field, the validation error is not updated.

Please find the full code example [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/agitated-goldstine-vl79ty?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

I tried to trigger the validations with trigger function from  useForm but not always works. this in the onChange event on each select input

```
setTimeout(() => {
    trigger()
}, 400)
```

also tried to get the error from

```
control._formState.errors
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `validation/index.tsx`, pull `clearErrors` from `useForm` and `isValid` from `formstate` then use them with `useEffect` in same file. This will clear all errors in the form  if form is valid.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isValid) {
      clearErrors();
    }
  }, [isValid])
```